# "values-in-rID" resources folder android stands for what?

Tags: android, localization

App i am working on supports Indonesian locale, I do have

```
"values-in"
"values-in-rID"
```

resource folders.Both contains strings only.

I didn't find any info regarding **"values-in-rID"**. i can see its getting used [here too](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/9e9b6169a098bc19986e44fbbf65e4c29031e4bd/sdk/platforms/android-22/data/res) in android sdk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`values-in` means Indonesian Locale, and in all regions.
`values-in-rID` means Indonesian Locale, but applies only in the region of Indonesia. The `r` here means `region`.

The following screenshot should make things clear.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

These are language and locale codes. For example, French in France is not entirely the same as French in Canada, so you might see `fr-FR` and `fr-CA` used to differentiate them instead of just using `fr`.

Comment: yeah i got that info from https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html, but no info about "in-rID"

Answer (score 0):

Android has a resource fallback mechanism that uses this folder naming pattern. Imagine your app has language resources for French(France) in a folder `values-fr-rFR`, resources for French(Switzerland) in a folder `values-fr-rCH` and resources that are the same for France and Switzerland in a folder `values-fr`. For the app locale French(Switzerland) Android will first attempt to load resources from the `values-fr-rCH` folder and then fall back to `values-fr`. See [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support.html) for further details.

So, the folder `values-in-rID` contains resources for usage in Indonesian as spoken/written in Indonesia. Whether this approach makes sense for Indonesian or not I don't know: it certainly does if a variant of Indonesian is used outside of Indonesia. Anyway, make sure to provide a set of default resources as well as your Indonesian resources, as described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html).